# Resty Resolver issue Python

Tags: python, flask, connexion

I was following a tutorial: https://medium.com/@ssola/building-microservices-with-python-part-i-5240a8dcc2fb

```
from connexion.resolver import RestyResolver
import connexion

items = {
    0: {"name": "First item"}
}


def search():
    return items

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = connexion.App(__name__, 9090, specification_dir='swagger/')
    app.add_api('my_super_app.yaml', resolver=RestyResolver('api'))
    app.run()
```

I keep getting the same error: `ImportError: No module named items`
Does any one know how to resolve this error? I pip installed all the dependencies

Here is api.itmes

```
items = {
    0: {"name": "First item"}
}


def search() -> list:
    return items
```

Here is my_super_app.yaml

```
swagger: "2.0"

info:
  title: "My first API"
  version: "1.0"

basePath: /v1.0

paths:
  /items/:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 'Fetch a list of items'
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/Item'

definitions:
  Item:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      name: { type: string }
```

Error produced:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "connexion.options"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rabiaasif/Documents/GitHub/MibsBackEnd/marble-project/marbles/flask/bff.py", line 15, in <module>
    app.add_api('my_super_app.yaml', resolver=RestyResolver('api'))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/connexion/apps/flask_app.py", line 54, in add_api
    api = super(FlaskApp, self).add_api(specification, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/connexion/apps/abstract.py", line 155, in add_api
    options=api_options.as_dict())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.add_paths()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 212, in add_paths
    self._handle_add_operation_error(path, method, err.exc_info)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 226, in _handle_add_operation_error
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/connexion/resolver.py", line 64, in resolve_function_from_operation_id
    return self.function_resolver(operation_id)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/connexion/utils.py", line 99, in get_function_from_name
    raise last_import_error
ImportError: No module named items
```

Comment: Have you tried importing the module? `import api`

Comment: Please show the full traceback. @Eqomatic I would be surprised if there is any module called just `api`

Comment: https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#running-it

Comment: @roganjosh I was also surprised. https://pypi.org/project/api/

Comment: In the tutorial there is an api.items, there is some file called api.items...I think it is referring to that I'm just not sure how to work around this error the tutorial wasn't very specific

Answer (score 1):

Whilst in you virtualenv, execute;
`pip install connexion[swagger-ui]`

The above will fix your error, `No handlers could be found for logger "connexion.options"` at the top of your error produced.

I was having a similar issue. After I installed connexion with a bit extra (the above), it had solved other errors I had.

I found this in the README of [bitshares-explorer-api](https://github.com/oxarbitrage/bitshares-explorer-api)